# How to change datasource of details control c#

Tags: c#

I have a project that has a details control with various text boxes along side a data grid view control. I have a refresh button which updates the data grid view. This is my code for this button:

```
string text = userIDLabel1.Text;
int currentUserID;
int.TryParse(text, out currentUserID);

//update datagridview
string dgvconn = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\CW\CW\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
string sql = "select * from Records where UserID = @CurrentUserID";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dgvconn);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
dataadapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUserID", currentUserID);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter2.Fill(ds, "Records");
connection.Close();
recordsDataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
recordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds;
recordsDataGridView.DataMember = "Records";
```

Before I refresh the data grid view whenever I select a row, the details control text boxes automatically change to the values corresponding to the row chosen. However when I refresh the datagridview the details control textboxes no longer change.

Is this because I am assigning the datagridview with a new data set / datasource and not doing the same to the details control?

Thanks for any help in advance,

Dan

Comment: If you post the binding code for the details control, that might help, if the schema of the refreshed data is different, the bindings would be off.

Comment: How do I see the binding code? And how do I change the schema so it is the same?

Comment: The detail controls are being bound to the selected table row of the datagridview. The code for one of the detail controls. It should be something like `DataBindings.Add(`

Comment: I apologize but that doesn’t really help me not sure what it means, how do I make bind the details view to the same as the data grid view?

Comment: Okay I think I know what u mean by how I find out the name of the details control?

Comment: Changing the datasource doesn't automatically repaint the grid.  So trick is set source to null. recordsDataGridView.DataSource = null; recordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds;

Comment: Not sure what you mean can you please elaborate

Comment: You should use a binding source. You may have one already and mistakenly overwriting it. You should have a binding source for the grid data and then the detail controls should continue to work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yes but I have to make a new data source when I filter the data grid to display most recent first for example. Can I assign the details control to the same data source?

Comment: Yes, it's kind of confusing at first. If you already have one, you just do `bindingSource1.DataSouce = newTable;` . If you dont have one, drag a new `BindingSource` from the toolbox anywhere on your form and use it in code